# How to sort Map by two factors?

Tags: java

I have a Map, and I want to sort by two factors:

```
1) the int value of each element; and then
2) the length of key of each element.
```

This generic function can sort by value, and how to make it work for sorting by both 1) and 2)?

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue(Map<K, V> unsortMap) {

        List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list = new LinkedList<>(unsortMap.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {
                return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
            }
        });

        Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Edit: this version doesn't work quite right. Anything wrong?

```
public static Map<String, Integer> sortByValueWithGenerics(Map<String, Integer> unsortMap) {

        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list =
                new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(unsortMap.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1,
                               Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                int c = (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());


                if (c < 0) {
                    if(o2.getKey().length() >o1.getKey().length()){
                        c=-1;
                    }
                }

                return c;
            }
        });

        Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
            sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        return sortedMap;
    }
```

Comment: Since this intended to work for generic key and value types could you please clarify what you mean by *int value*, do you mean the standard `compareTo` implementation of `V`? And *key length*, as the key `K` could be any object, how are judging length?

Comment: I mean based on the length of a String key, since my Map is of <String, Integer>.

Comment: In that case, your function will have to make reference to the specific types, and not be as generic as you are presenting it there.

Comment: You mean sort the element base on value and if value of 2 elements are equal then sort on length of key?

Comment: @You'reawesome. Yes. that's what i want.

Comment: @d.j.brown, but i received "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!" with your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition should check if the previous comparison returned `0` then perform the following comparison like this:

```
if (c == 0) 
   return Integer.compare(o1.getKey().length(), o2.getKey().length());
```

Also, note that I've passed the `o1.getKey().length()` as the first argument to the `Integer.compare` method as opposed to passing it as the second argument as you've done.

Now, your comparator reads as "sort by value and if two given values are equal then sort by the length of the key ascending".

---

As of java-8, you can further simplify the sort logic to:

```
list.sort(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue()
                      .thenComparingInt(e -> e.getKey().length());
```

or if you want to get even fancier then the entire method can become:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> sortByValueThenByKey(Map<String, Integer> unsortMap) {
      return unsortMap.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue()
                       .thenComparingInt(e -> e.getKey().length()))
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                     Map.Entry::getValue,(oldValue, newValue) -> newValue, 
                             LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

Comment: I think you may want to add that the second example only works in Java 8 (I think)